# Can 3 planes intersect at a single point?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I know that three planes can intersect having a common straight line as intersection. But I have seen in some references that three planes intersect at single point.The three planes were represented by a triangle.
What is equation of a triangle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really? Are you familiar with $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: They can be triangularly shaped.

Comment: Two non-parallel planes intersect in a line. If that line is not parallel to the third plane, then it passes through it at a single point.

Comment: what about the three coordinate planes??

Comment: Thanks for the satisfactory answer. Also can you please let me know how the equation of a  triangular plane is written?

Comment: The x-y,y-z and z-x plane intersecting at origin.

Answer (score 7):

The general equation for a plane is $ax+by+cz=d$ for constants $a,b,c,d.$

I can't comment on the *specific* example you saw; you may often see a triangle as a representation of a portion of a plane in a particular octant. But three planes can certainly intersect at a point: consider the three coordinate planes, $x=0,y=0,z=0$.

[image]

And if you want all possibilities:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Golden_Ratio. Very nice.

Comment: Thanks   @PeterSzilas