# Understanding the different possibilities of three planes intersection and leading to solutions to system of linear equations of three variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems

Suppose we have system of three equations which are non-homogenous . They are basically planes represented in $3$ dimensional coordinate axis. So solution to the system of three linear non homogenous system is equivalent to finding intersection points of planes in the coordinate axis.  Now here are the possible outcomes which can happen when three planes intersect :
**A)** they intersect together at a single point .
**B)** they intersect together on a common intersection line .
**C)** all of them intersecting in different common line for each pair .
**D)** Two planes being parallel and not having any intersectiom point but another plane which cuts both have two common lines with respect to them .
**E)** All three planes being parallel to each other.
**F)** all three being same plane.
**G)** two of them representing  same plane while the last one cuts it in common line.

> So out of these only
> A ) determines a unique point common , which also implies determiant of the coefficient of the variables  is non zero and rank of the matrix being 3.       While B ) gives a infinite solutions to the system . Which also implies that third system is a linear combination of first two system , and this also tells rank of the coefficient matrix is 2 .   Other two D) and  E) are cases of system being inconsistent . They all have determinant being zero but also that rank is 2 and 1 respectively.
> While F) and G) are again consistent system which have infinite solutions and det being zero and rank respectively 1 and 2  . I most probably understood and gave correct description to all these cases except the **case of C** where i am not getting what can be said about determinant and also rank as such  all three would look like its all different equations so deteminant is non zero but then if i apply cramer rule here then it will have a solution which contradicts the fact shown by graph thats its inconsistent .  C case graph , this shows the three planes intersection top view which are being formed : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intersect the planes two at a time, you’ll get three lines, in general. Case (C) describes a configuration where these three lines are parallel and distinct, so there is no point where all three planes intersect.

Geometrically, the normal vectors of the three planes are coplanar (i.e. linearly dependent), and this means that the determinant formed from these three vectors is zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot understood , and Sir these are the only 7 cases possible right ? I mean no other case possible ?

Comment: I think that’s true. But I can’t immediately think of a good way to reliably enumerate all the possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact 8 cases, you are missing when 2 planes are coincident and parallel to the 3rd, i.e. case 3 below ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4363075/1203882)):
[image: 8 cases img]
Additionally, this statement (about case 8 above, your case C)

> all three would look like it’s all different equations so determinant is non zero

is false. As @bubba explained, the plane normals are linearly dependent (non-trivially, as in none is a scalar multiple of another, you actually need a combination), implying the row rank is $2$. $\text{rank}\,A=2<\dim \mathbb{R}^3$ means the determinant is in fact $0$, so in particular, you cannot apply Cramer’s rule, and there is no contradiction as you suggested.

A complete characterization of all 8 cases ([source](https://splash.tdchristian.ca/classes/math/textbooks/MCV4Uetext/cvsb_520.pdf)):
[image: 8 cases sys]
However, as the source is a very elementary text, it does not give an algebraic (as opposed to algorithmic / computational) way to distinguish them, with no mention of determinants, rank, or even matrices.

I haven't thought of or seen any clever way to distinguish *all* 8 cases (using e.g. linear or geometric algebra), other than considering all pairwise intersections of planes, as @bubba alluded to. But I believe it can be done, extending what you have so far using for example homogeneous coordinates or something called [PGA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-based_geometric_algebra) to properly handle the inconsistent cases of intersections at infinity. It's a question I'm interested in myself, so I'll update this answer if I come up with anything.

Comment: Please don't use links to answer a question.

Comment: Noted, thank you for the advice.